# HTML li tag - edit space when wordwrap

Tags: html, css

I am working with HTML and CSS and I am trying to get the lines closer when my line word wraps.

[image]

I am trying to get the space between smaller. How can I do that with CSS?

Comment: try to use `line-height`. Also post your code for us to see

Comment: give us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the `line-height` property.

It is used like this

```
p{
  line-height: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want the [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) to be smaller.

```
ul {
    line-height: 1;
}
```